# How to perform an action when a text message is received?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app that will send an automated response every time a text message is received.  I [looked around a bit](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=text%20message&t=0) on android's development site but haven't had anything that points me in the right direction.  Does anyone have any ideas on where I should start with this or have any good links that might help?

I am a total beginner with developing Android apps so please bear with me if I'm a little slow with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a BroadcastReceiver to receive the SMS Intent as well as update your manifest to ask for the permission to recieve and register for SMS broadcasts.

There are plenty of simple examples available online.  Here are the first three I found.

- http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android
- http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/
- http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/